# Why isn't the word for triangle トラヤングル?

Tags: phonetics

What's the phonetic difference between toraianguru (トライアングル, the correct word in Japanese) and torayanguru (トラヤングル)? Do they both sound the same and it's purely a matter of orthography, or is there some deeper difference?

Comment: For me, not native: トラヤングル the YA seems a little harsh and over powering...

Comment: Related: [Why do some loanword sounds get “contracted” when katakanized, but not others?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18878/78).

Comment: I think トライヤングル is more possible than トラヤングル because there are similar examples as タイヤ, ダイヤモンド, ワイヤー, etc. However, there is neither.

Answer (score 2):

In short, they don't sound the same: [ト]{to}[ラ]{ra}[イ]{i}[ア]{a}[ン]{n}[グ]{gu}[ル]{ru} sounds closer to the pronunciation of the English source term.  The `/aia/` vowel combination (as `/a i a/`) makes a clear analog of the English `/aia/` pronunciation (as `/aɪ æ/` for the `i` and `a` in the middle of *tr**ia**ngle*).

Meanwhile, [ト]{to}[ラ]{ra}[ヤ]{ya}[ン]{n}[グ]{gu}[ル]{ru} has no `/ai/` combination at all, and doesn't sound as close to the English term.

(Musings: rather than [ト]{to}[ラ]{ra}[ヤ]{ya}[ン]{n}[グ]{gu}[ル]{ru}, a closer phonetic match might be [ト]{to}[ラ]{ra}[イ]{i}[エ]{e}[ン]{n}[グ]{gu}[ル]{ru}.)

Comment: That phonetic for 'triangle' might be true for America, but certainly not for (most parts of) Britain.

Comment: @Nothingatall -- If you mean the `/aɪ æ/` for the `i` and `a` in the middle of *tr**ia**ngle*, how would other British accents pronounce this?  C.f. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triangle#Pronunciation.

Comment: The a in triangle is generally /a/ in British accents; トライアングル is perfect fit, whereas トライエングル would sound off.

Comment: It's actually /æ/ in British accents.  See the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary.

Comment: @snailboat In traditional RP, yes, but most modern British accents have /a/.

Comment: @Nothingatall Which vowel do you mean by /a/?  Perhaps /ɑː/?  English has no /a/ phoneme, so it's unclear.

Comment: @snailboat Modern identifications of British accents use /a/ for a low front unrounded vowel. Certainly not a back vowel as you give.

Comment: @Nothingatall Please cite your sources.  I am not saying you mean any particular vowel, just guessing based on the visual resemblance between ‹a› and ‹ɑ›.  Since English has no phoneme indicated by the former, I have to guess what you mean, and I can't guess correctly since you use non-standard transcription conventions.

Comment: @Nothingatall My only other guess is that you're accidentally putting a phonetic transcription in forward slashes instead of square brackets.  Do you mean /æ/ is pronounced [a]?  That seems more reasonable, as BrE /æ/ is quite low.  (See e.g. the chart in *A Course in Phonetics*, 6th ed., p.90)

Answer (score 2):

A part of the reason is nontransparent transcriptions are generally not approved in Japanese. The word *triangle* obviously splits up into *tri* + *angle*, thus we favor the spelling トライ{tri} + アングル{angle}, which reminds us of the original breakpoint. If English *triangle* should sound トラヤングル (while it doesn't to me), I don't think much people write it directly under today's convention.

The rule holds true even if syllable linking occurs, such as: ログ{log}イン{in}, キック{kick}オフ{off}, ポップ{pop}アップ{up} etc. There are indeed some usages in blogosphere that like [ホッテントリ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%A5%DB%A5%C3%A5%C6%A5%F3%A5%C8%A5%EA) "hot entry" or プラギン "plugin", but they're all intended geekish slangs.

In [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18878/7810) @istrasci has suggested, you can see some exceptions like パイナップル{pineapple} and ラインナップ{lineup} (and ランナウェイ{runaway}, ワンナウト{one out} etc.), yet they're only allowed in *n + vowel* environment.

**PS**
I don't know if this is trivial enough, but, purely from Japanese standpoint, トライアングル and トラヤングル would not sound the same. The former is seven morae long, the latter six.